# How to past data from array into part of html body

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to pass on element from array into to html body, so far i have:

```
 Public example As String
```

then function that returns on element from array

```
Sub products()
Dim aArray() As String

For j = 2 To 2
If Cells(j, 1).Value <> "" Then
ReDim aArray(1 To 1) As String
For i = 1 To 10

If Cells(j, i).Value = "Yes" Then
    aArray(UBound(aArray)) = Cells(1, i).Value
    ReDim Preserve aArray(1 To UBound(aArray) + 1) As String
End If

Next i
example = Left(Join(aArray, " & "), Len(Join(aArray, " & ")) - 3) ''example is one of the product name
 End If
Next j
Call mail
End Sub
```

and Ron Debruin email creator

```
Sub mail()

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next

Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

body_of_email = example
product_name_1 = "very, very, very long product1 info"
product_name_2 = "very, very, very long product2 info"
product_name_3 = "very, very, very long product3 info"
product_name_4 = "very, very, very long product4 info"

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & body_of_email
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

What should I change to make "body_of_email" returns one of the 'product info' into HTMLBody not the 'example' from array?
thanks for any help!

edit

when i changed this line

```
.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & body_of_email
```

into this

```
      Select Case wynik 
Case Is = "product_name_1 " 
.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & product_name_1 
Case Is = "product_name_2 " 
.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & product_name_2 
Case Is = "product_name_3 " 
.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & product_name_3 
Case Is = "product_name_4 " 
.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & product_name_4 
        End Select
```

it helped

Comment: `RangeToHTML` converts the selected `rng` object into HTML. You can't just *append* a string to that as you've adapted your code. The `RangeToHTML` function creates the body (`.HTMLBody` property) of the `Outlook.MailItem`. I think you need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: Code doesn't render in the comments, your comment is impossible to read. Please edit the question to reflect the code as currently used, also please describe the error (if any) or how the output differs from your expectations (if no error raised).